# Analyzing cost of treatment in a cohort (varying follow up/available data) at multiple time points

Tags: survival, panel-data, dataset, bias, censoring

I would like to look at total cost of treatment from an index date (treatment initiation) after 1 month, 3 month, and 6 months.

However, my data has has issues where patients drop out at varying time points (after 2 months, 4 months, 5 months).

If my question is: For patients who initiated on treatment, what does their total cost of care (treatment + hospitalizations) look like at each time point, what is the best way to analyze this data?

My two ideas right now (Hypothetical 100 patient cohort) are:

1. Assess 1/3/6-month costs for patients who are on treatment for that long. (Ex. 80/100 still on treatment at 6 months, aggregate costs across 6 months for those 80 patients and run summary stats)
2. Assess per month costs for patients who are on treatment. (Ex. Costs in month 1 for 100 patients + Costs in month 2 for 95 pats + ... + Costs in month 6 for 80 pats).

This is a descriptive analysis. Which method is recommended? Can you please provide examples in the literature to support this?

Thanks

Comment: It may seem reasonable to summarize separately results for the 80 who persisted for the full time period and for all 100 patients some of whom stopped treatment earlier. However, it might be better to summarize separately the 80 who persisted, and the 20 who did not. That would allow for a possible direct comparison between the two different groups. Generally, it is not a good idea to encourage comparison of a subgroup with a containing full group.

Comment: @BruceET can you please clarify? Say my question is total cost of care among those treated with therapy at 6 months, would you look total costs across 6 months for the 80 with complete data? I do not have 6 months worth of data for the other 20 due to loss to follow up.

Comment: I would separate the two groups entirely. Provide costs at 3 months for both groups. (Are costs different for those who quit early?) Then separately, provide costs for 6 months for the groups who persisted with treatment for 6 months.

Comment: Thanks @BruceET. Just so I understand, run analysis on months 1-3 on the 80 and 20 separately, then run analysis on months 4-6 on the 80. Should I also do an expected cost for month 1-3 on all 100?